# Mod Rewrite Question

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following directory: http://www.mydomain.com/issues/issue-04/

And I have the following mod rewrite in place, it works well.

```
RewriteRule ^issue-04/?$ /issues/issue-04/ [L]
```

It simply hides the "issues" directory from the user so they just see: http://www.mydomain.com/issue-04/

Inside my issue-04 page though, I have a link which reaches out to an absolute URL as follows:

http://www.mydomain.com/issue-04/goodies/card1.png

I was hoping anything going through the **/issue-04/** directory would just resolve itself. But I guess that's not how it works. How can I go about guiding anything inside the **/issue-04** directory through the unseen **/issues** directory using a simple rule?

I want any link with **/issue-04** to go through **/issues/issue-04**, so in theory if I were to target any of the files inside the **/issue-04** directory I could do so by dropping the "issues" parent path

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^issue\-([0-9]+)((/[\w\-\._]*)*)$ /issues/issue-$1$2 [L]
```

It should work with or without slash after the issue, will work for any issue number, not just 4..

Comment: I love this solution, works great and applied nicely to all my other issues. Great thinkin', thanks!

Comment: That says you can have a section of 0 or more characters that are letters+digits (\w) or dash (\-) or dot (\.) or underscore (_) which needs to be preceded by a slash. In other words a "folder" or file name or just a slash alone. You can add here other characters that may appear in your urls such as #, !, ~ etc. That is the first group: (/[\w\-\._]). Then this group can itself appear zero or more times which means you can stop after the issue number (0 groups) of have any number of folders or file names (1+ groups).

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
RewriteRule ^issue-04/(.*)$ /issues/issue-04/$1 [L]
```

But the above means that you have to have a slash after `issue-04` : e.g. this will work `http://www.mydomain.com/issue-04/` (as well as `http://www.mydomain.com/issue-04/goodies/card1.png` of course) but this will not `http://www.mydomain.com/issue-04`.

To have it working with or without slash after `issue-04`, better split it into 2 rules (first will work without slash and second will handle the rest) -- this is the easiest approach:

```
RewriteRule ^issue-04$ /issues/issue-04/ [L]
RewriteRule ^issue-04/(.*)$ /issues/issue-04/$1 [L]
```